# How do I install Linux on a bricked Samsung Galaxy 10.1 SM-P600 Tablet?

Tags: rom-flashing, factory-reset

Steps I took:

1. Downloaded Samsung drivers and installed
2. Downloaded Odin v1.85
3. Booted up tablet and pressed "Volume Down" button, ran Odin and began download
4. Turned off tablet when I shouldn't have...

When I boot it up, I get a message which reads, "Firmware upgrade encountered an issue.  Please select recovery mode in Kies & try again."

5. Connected the tablet to laptop, started Kies but it does not connect

Ran it again in Odin mode and KNOX warranty is voided. Also doesn't connect.

Is there a reliable way to reinstall stock firmware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and figured it out!

I found an article which explained the different types of bricked devices and was able to follow their instruction.  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1133590

Basically, I went to sammobile.com and searched their firmware archive for the model number, downloaded it, accessed the download menu on the tablet by holding power and volume down, and ran it through ODIN v3.12.3.  The whole process took up my evening, but took off at breakneck speed once the download finished.

Hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue!

Comment: Just noticed that you used Odin 1.85 (super old) in the original question O_o Glad you solved it after research. Mark your own answer as accepted for some renown :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a video I watched which does a good job of explaining the solution.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLAygzQr3VY